# How to rearrange print output in Python from column to a row?

Tags: image-processing, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, mahotas

I wrote a method computing Robert Haralick image features (using Mahotas package) on .tif medical images in the working directory. I receive the print output in  a column like:

```
567657657
788979877
787879787
```

I need to convert it to the horizontal row appearance like: `1789789  8909888 898098098`
and, if possible, append the name of the processed file before that row of output (like: `imagename 7897987 90890898...`). Here is the code:

```
def haralick(self):
   for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
      imgg = mahotas.imread (filename)
      cancertwo = mahotas.features.haralick (imgg)
      arr = numpy.array([cancertwo])
      for x in arr:
          for y in arr:
              for h in y:
                  for z in h:
                      print '%f' %z
                      print('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.x versions do an automatic newline after a print statement, but you can stop it from doing this with a `,` (and with `,` you get an automatic space).

In your code just use the single line (without an explicit `\n`):

```
print "%i" %z,
```

(I assume you're using a 2.x version for access to a full scientific stack for medical image processing, but please mention it if you're not.)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Python; If you mean however to print the **same** numbers consecutive to console or file or whatever, it will be just a matter of not printing the \n\r character but substituting them with for example a tab \t or a comma ',',

Comment: Thank you, but what code do you suggest, solving the problem?

Comment: Try changing print('\n') to print('\t') and observe the output